# VSCode Extension Development - My extension webview reload when i come back with focus from another vscode tab

Tags: vscode-extensions, svelte

I'm working on a vscode extension that works with a webview and i'm new to vscode extension and web development.

I made a webview with svelte but everytime i switch to another tab and come back to my webview's tab everything reloads.
I generated the html of the webview by a function who alse load the compiled components made in svelte.

```js
function getGenericHTML(_webview: vscode.Webview, _extensionUri: vscode.Uri , _compiledElementName:string) : string {
    // Local path to css styles in media folder
    const stylesResetUri = _webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(_extensionUri,"media","reset.css"));
    const stylesMainUri = _webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(_extensionUri,"media","vscode.css"));
    const stylesBootstrap = _webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(_extensionUri,"media","bootstrap.min.css"));
    const scriptBootstrap = _webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(_extensionUri,"media","bootstrap.bundle.min.js"));
  
    // Svelte compiled elements
    const scriptUri = _webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(_extensionUri, "out", "compiled", _compiledElementName + ".js"));
    const cssUri = _webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(_extensionUri, "out", "compiled", _compiledElementName + ".css"));

    // Use a nonce to only allow specific scripts to be run
    const nonce = getNonce();

    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src https: data:; style-src 'unsafe-inline' ${ _webview.cspSource }; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <link href="${stylesBootstrap}" rel="stylesheet" integrity=${"sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"} crossorigin="anonymous">
                    <link href="${stylesResetUri}" rel="stylesheet">
                    <link href="${stylesMainUri}" rel="stylesheet">
                    <link href="${cssUri}" rel="stylesheet">
                    <script nonce="${nonce}">
                        tsvscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
                    </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                </body>
                <script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptUri}"></script>
                <script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptBootstrap}" integrity=${"sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"} crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            </html>`;
}
```

I need to declare the files to execute once? Did i miss something? Does anyone have some advice?

The full code of the extension is on github: https://github.com/ArkoMO93/al-translations.git

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. If the webview is not visible, VS Code destroys it to reclaim memory. The webview is then automatically recreated when it becomes visible again. See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#persistence for details about how to preserve state between unloads and reloads

If this doesn't work for your use case, you can enable [`retainContextWhenHidden`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#retaincontextwhenhidden) in the `WebviewPanelOptions`. Again though, only do this if you absolutely need to

Comment: Matt, can you give a few numbers related to resource usage of an average webview? Why is it a problem to retain them, given that todays computers have lots of RAM?

Comment: It's around 50MB for an empty webview. Which isn't the end of the world, until you have 20+ webview tabs all open in the background (while also doing whatever background computing they feel like). If you don't need to use the resources, don't